# University names?

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

I have some questions concerning names of university.

1. What is the difference between "The Poznan University of Life
   Sciences" and "Poznan University of Life Sciences"?
2. Are there any grammatical rules for a university's name?
3. Where and when should we put "the" before the name?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "The" is sometimes dropped from a proper noun's title.  There is no practical difference between the two, other than making it clear that it is an individual article.
2. A university's name is a proper noun, and should be capitalized as such.
3. "The" is used formally to refer to a university as an individual article.  In most cases it can be dropped.